# How do I set input field size so that after entering 4 words in input it jumps to the next field?

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

This is my code. I'm using stripe code fields

**Card number**

```
<label>
    <span style="width:151px;">Card Number</span>
    <input type="text" size="20" class="field" data-stripe="number" placeholder="4242-4242-4242-4242"/>
</label>
```

**CVC number size 3**

```
<label>
    <span style="width:151px;"> CVC</span>
    <input type="text" size="3" class="field" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC"/>
</label>
```

**Month size 2 and year 4**

```
 <label>
      <span style="width:151px;">Expiration(MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" class="field" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM"/>
      <input type="text" size="4" class="field" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YY"/>
 </label>
```

Comment: by 4 words do you mean 4 sets of numbers in the card input.. which could also include hyphens?

Comment: Yes as payment gateway use..after edit cvc number jump to next field then month of two digits then jump to next field ..

Comment: so jumping after cvc is different, first a cvc can be 3 or 4 numbers depending on card type. Also if you're not enforcing format of car number it could be `1111222333444` or `1111 2222 3333 4444` or `1111-2222-3333-4444` - this kind of thing makes a difference to the solutions

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer to your question, but if possible, I'd recommend that you switch to using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) (Stripe.js v3) instead of Stripe.js v2.

Not only will it take care of formatting the card number automatically, it will also make you eligible for PCI SAQ A, while with Stripe.js v2, you'd fall under the more cumbersome PCI SAQ A-EP. (More information about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance).)